# How to thank or apologize to an associate editor of a journal?

Tags: paper-submission, editors, policy

Suppose that when submitting a paper to a journal I made a mistake that resulted in some rule violation. No one detected this rule violation until the decision was announced. Once the decision was announced, the associate editor sent me an email to warn me for future submission.

I would like to reply to him/her. What should I write? An apology? A thanking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply write a brief email along the lines of "Thanks for notifying me of the mistake, I will bear that in mind for future submissions. Apologies that I didn't catch it sooner."